# Como Exibir varios valores de um JSON em PHP

Tags: php, json

Como posso exibir todos os valores de um JSON em PHP ??

Vou dar um exemplo , Uso o Código abaixo para requisitar o JSON

```
    $json_file = file_get_contents("http://backpack.tf/api/IGetUsers/v3/?steamids=76561198012598620");

    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
```

As informações contidas no JSON São estas:

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1400075229,
        "players": {
            "76561198012598620": {
                "steamid": "76561198012598620",
                "success": 1,
                "backpack_value": {
                    "570": 5,
                    "440": 126.9475
                },
                "backpack_update": {
                    "570": 1399815523,
                    "440": 1400024876
                },
                "name": "Fiskie",
                "backpack_tf_reputation": 2,
                "notifications": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mas se uso

```
$nome = $json_str["name"];
echo "$nome";
```

Para exibir o valor "name" a pagina parece não carregar , toda a tela fica branca..

Como posso exibir o valor "name" corretamente ?

Obrigado a todos que puderem me ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$nome = $json_str["response"]["players"]["76561198012598620"]["name"];
echo "$nome";
```

Comment: Obrigado !! funcionou Perfeitamente